# Why does my font-size property not work for any element in css?

Tags: html, css

The font-size property does not work for any element when I write in an external css file but works fine in inline css. There are no contradicting tags involved. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

```
.navbar-brand {
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```
<section id="title">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Nav Bar -->

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sharma</a>
```

Comment: your question has not have enough information to solve your problem, but some questions should be helpful.

Comment: who you import or attach your external CSS file into your HTML file?

Comment: are you using some pre-processor or post-processor like SASS, LESS, SCSS in your style file?

Comment: are you using webpack or some module bundler like webpack?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you are importing your css corectly, Use your browser inspect tools to find what rule is conflicting with yours css.

Comment: I found the problem but can't find a way to solve it. The problem is predefined margins given by bootstrap itself. I can't overwrite the values. It neglects my values and only applies the one given by bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar-brand {
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section id="title">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Nav Bar -->

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sharma</a>
```

It is working.

Comment: I found the problem but can't find a way to solve it. The problem is predefined margins given by bootstrap itself. I can't overwrite the values. It neglects my values and only applies the one given by bootstrap.

Comment: To fix that, you may need to first insert the stylesheet  for boostrap then override it by inserting a style tag after it